# How to convert an 'if, else, else if' in a component to a switchcase scenario based on a ngModel value?

Tags: angular

I have a button which previews an image when uploaded. Currently, to stop all buttons using the same click event and thus, showing the same image, I have an if, 'else if', 'else'  condition in the component to define which image to show on preview based on ngModel in the HTML. I was wondering if it is possible to convert this to a switch-case scenario instead? The code works, but I'm sure that there is a cleaner or less monolithic way in which to write it. I was thinking that a switch-case might be a better way.

**component.ts**

```
preview() {
    var mimeType = this.fileData.type;
    if (mimeType.match(/image\/*/) == null) {
      return;
    }
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.fileData);
    reader.onload = (_event) => {
      if (this.selectedLeagueBadge) {
        this.leagueBadgePreviewUrl = reader.result;
      } else if (this.selectedAwayBadge) {
        this.awayBadgePreviewUrl = reader.result;
      } else if (this.selectedHeader) {
        this.headerPreviewUrl = reader.result;
      } else {
        this.previewUrl = reader.result;
      }
    }
  }
```

**.component.html**

```
   <li>
    <button class="update" (click)="openForm('club_badge')">
    {{ show_form['club_badge'] ? 'Close' : 'Change Image' }}
    </button>
   </li>
   <ng-container *ngIf="show_form['club_badge']">
      <input type="file" name="club_badge 
      [(ngModel)]="selectedClubBadge"
      (change)="fileProgress($event)" accept=".jpg,.svg,.png,.jpeg">
      <div class="image_preview" *ngIf="previewUrl">
        <img [src]="previewUrl | safe:'resourceUrl'">
      </div>
      <button class="update (click)="uploadImage($event)">Upload</button>
   </ng-container>
```

**other ngModel values**

```
<input type="file" name="home_page_background" 
[(ngModel)]="selectedHomePageBackgroundImage"
(change)="fileProgress($event)" accept=".jpg,.svg,.png,.jpeg">

<input type="file" name="default_header" 
[(ngModel)]="selectedHeader"
(change)="fileProgress($event)" accept=".jpg,.svg,.png,.jpeg">
```

in the above is there a way to differentiate between selectedHomePageBackgroundImage & selectedHeader in order to create the switch?

As mentioned before, this works, but I think this could be better and from searching the net, I am getting back lots of switch-case docs for the DOM instance of ngSwitchCase, which isn't what I am referring to.

Has anyone worked this out before?

Comment: I didn't understand well your issue which part you want to modify, i presume it's the  preview function you want to modify. Switch case is not working ? You seems to have already checked some docs about it. You need to have a single var where you choose the "type", on this var you will use switch-case scenario

Comment: So basically, refrain from using if else conditions in the component and switch them out based on an input field that is being opened. It just seems messy.